# Python function not counting all consecutive instances of three letter sequence

Tags: python, string

This is a function to find the consecutive occurrences of a three letter string within a larger string of just letters with no spaces (it is a dna sequence). I wrote this to count it by splitting the string into a list first; however, it is not properly working. For example, `mutation("TACAGCAGCAGTCAGCAGA")` ought to return `3`, but, through my code, it return `2`. I printed the list it is using, so I know the issue is with how I splitting the original string into a list. I am at a loss at how to fix it. Is there a way to iterate and count through the string in blocks of three characters, or did I have the right idea trying to use a list? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
def mutation(dna):
    #first need to split string into list of codons 
    codon_list = [] #initialize codon list
    i = 0 #initialize step
    #write a for loop 
    n = 3
    for i in range(i, len(dna), n):
        codon_list.append(dna[i:i+3])
      
    #initialize variables 
    count = 0
    pointer = 0
    max_consec = 0
    #use a while loop to count occurrences of CAG
    while count < len(codon_list):
        
        if codon_list[count] == 'CAG':
            pointer += 1 
            if pointer > max_consec: 
                max_consec = pointer
        else: 
            pointer = 0
            
        count += 1 

    return max_consec
```

Comment: You only consider substrings starting at indices that are multiples of 3. Why don't you just do `dna.count('CAG')`?

Comment: Why should that return 3?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille That's how DNA works, it's groups of 3 bases.

Comment: In this case, there are only 2 'CAG' sequences in the sequence the OP provided, and the output of the code is right.

Comment: Right. One of the `CAG` is not a codon, it's split across `TAC` and `AGC`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to solve this using a regular expression how about the following first you can find the longest sequence of "sub_str" in "dna" using the below that will return the maximum consecutive occurrences, then divide strings lengths respectively.

```
import re

def mutation(dna, sub_str):
   res = max(re.findall('((?:' + re.escape(sub_str) + ')*)', dna), key = len)
   return len(res)/len(sub_str)
```

It is not including some edge cases make sure to test for your own needs